# Need guidance adding reporting capability to existing .Net Core web app

Tags: c#, .net-core, reporting

We developed a C# .Net Core 2.0 app with a SQL Server back-end. Now we want to add reports. We're looking for guidance on how to best implement reporting.

So far we see two options at our disposal 
1. SSRS (Sql Server Reporting Service) 
2. Telerik Reporting
But we are not sure of the best practice for implementing either option. Looking for guidance. Articles and examples we've found so far are either incorrect or obsolete.

We would like to display the reports within the app [ReportViewer], but if that's not possible rendering the report in a new browser tab is acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried out any of the suggested implementations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745526)? These include using SSRS' report execution webservice to render reports and return them back as a `byte[]` for downloading, and a custom control which mimics Microsoft's ReportViewer and works in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with wkhtmltopdf, a headless instance of chrome, and Razor pages.  This gives you the ability to implement reports using code and processes you're already familiar with.

You'll do this by building a Reports Controller, with an endpoint for each Report you'll want to generate. Have the endpoint return a View as normal.

Your converter will want to point itsself at this endpoint.  The returned view will be rendered to a PDF.  Alternatively, these views can be rendered in the browser as normal.  This means you get both without extra work that may be incurred with one of the other solutions.